# How to avoid migrations in python django

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I have a knowledge on .Net frameworks like asp.net, asp.net mvc and asp.net web api. Eventhough it is mvc or web api in .Net we get the data from database using few predefined classes. Then we create a model class object using which we send the data to UI. This approach we can say that 'database first approach'. Entity framework also we can use for same approach. I feel very comfortable with this approach.

Now I started study the Python Django. I am confusing a lot in the area of 'Migrations'. I am not comfort with django admin interface and migrations. Because I am very comfortable to write database queries, procedures and triggers.

I just want to bring the data from any database, after analysing will send to Django 'Template'. Remaining all areas of django are comfortable to me. I tried with django rest api's but there also i found 'Migrations' which are confusing me.

Any one please give me appropriate and detailed guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: aren't you confusing models and migrations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "Models" instead of "migrations" then well, you can of course bypass the ORM layer completely and do everything with raw sql instead if you whish...

... but seriously that would be a huge waste of time for at least 80% of common use cases. Django's ORM ("Models") actually makes life much easier for everything but really complex queries (analytics or like stuff), and does not prevent you to switch to raw sql for those queries.

NB : I don't have any problem with SQL either (I learned way before 'ORMs' went kind of mainstream) and still use raw SQL when it's the appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you bruno desthuilliers. So, we can perform the CRUD operations with out using 'Migrations' and 'Models'. right? In the 'View' how to extract the stored procedure data. Can you guide me...?